# Error: parse error on input ‘|’

Tags: haskell

```
libreDeCuadrados :: Integer -> Bool
libreDeCuadrados x = sumaPrimos x 2 0
  where 
    sumaPrimos x c s
               | c == x && s == x = True  -- Caso Base 1
               | c == x && s /= x = False -- Caso Base 2
               | x `mod` c == 0 && sumaPrimos x (c+1) (s+c) && esPrimo c
               | otherwise = sumaPrimos x (c+1) s
```

Tengo este código y me da el error que sale en el titulo. Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta un `=` en el tercer caso..

Answer (score 0):

Si, como dice Fydor falta un = en el tercer caso. Completa quedaría así `x`mod`c == 0 && sumaPrimos x (c+1) (s+c) && esPrimo c = True` (si el resto de dividir c entre x y la función `sumaPrimos` que toma como números el contenido de la variables x el siguiente de c y la suma de s+c y la función `esPrimo` aplicada a la variable c = True, cosa que tendría mucha lógica pues la firma de la función dice que tiene que devolver un `Bool`
PD. Presupongo que la función `esPrimo` esta definida.